# UI problems - How do I trigger an image loading on choice made by dropdown box? Then add text to overlay the image result?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm new to coding, I've learned the very basics of html/css/js/java, at least I thought I had, until I went to make a simple game.

I made a simple choose your own adventure game that worked, as each choice just went to a new page.

Then, I thought I'd make it a bit more complex, so I want to have the user enter their name, and store that to show next to the player's stats.
I've got a dropdown box with 4 choices for characters.I want to have Strength/Mana/Lives stats and have the player's choice of character to be able to adjust these stats accordingly before the game starts i.e. Male Warrior would have 2 extra Strength, Female Mage 2 extra mana etc.

Then, I'd like an image based on their character choice displayed next to their stats, so that the game can begin.

So far, I've been pulling my hair out in great clumps and have tried many different methods but so far, I've only got to the stage where I place the page with user input into an iframe. I can get to reflect their choices with text, but I can't get an image to load on submit. Ideally I'd like a permanent box in the top corner of the iframe, and have the statistics variables passed into the stats shown alongside the character's image.

I'd really really appreciate any help here, especially if it can be solved using HTML/CSS/JS as I'm not too familiar with JQuery, and would like to keep it as simple as possible really.
I've gone through as many q's and a's as I can to find relevant help, but I'm mainly finding answers for PHP or other languages.

I must apologise in advance for my waffling above, and sloppy coding. (I seriously thought this would be easy heh).
I'm unsure if my code so far will help, but I'll just paste it below anyway.

**HTML for the UI page is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Character Selection</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">

<style>
img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<div id='gamestitle'>
<p>

<img src = "GAMETITLE.jpg"
    alt = "Steve's Perilous Capers"/>
</p>
</div>
<br>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
<form id='nameForm'>
<div class='form-uname'>
    <lable id='nameLable' for='nameField'>Create a username:</lable>
    <input id='nameField' type='text' maxlength='25'></input>
</div>
<div class='form-sub'>
    <button id='subButton' type='button'>Enter your name!</button>
</div>
</form>
<div>
<p id='result'></p></div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
<form>
Select your Hero please:
<select id="mySelect">
<option>Male Warrior</option>
<option>Male Mage</option>
<option>Female Warrior</option>
<option>Female Mage</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Confirm">
</form>
</div>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**The CSS is:**

```
body {


margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

li {
list-style:none;
}

li.fields {
margin: 0;

padding: 1em 0;
}

li.title {
cursor: pointer;


font-weight: bold;
font-size : 1.5em;
line-height: 2em;
background: #e3e3e3;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.gamestitle {
max-width: 100%;
margin: auto;
}

.hide { display: none;}

.result {
 height: 200px;
width: 50%;
background-color: powderblue;
}
```

The JS file: (I've tried using icons and background image but I couldn't get them to show)

```
// the function which handles the input field logic
function getUserName() {
var nameField = document.getElementById('nameField').value;
var result = document.getElementById('result');

if (nameField.length < 3) {
    result.textContent = 'Username must contain at least 3 characters';
    //alert('Username must contain at least 3 characters');
} else {
    result.textContent = 'Your Hero is: ' + nameField;
    //alert(nameField);
}
}
function getOption() {
var obj = document.getElementById("mySelect");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
}
function swapImage(){
var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
image.src = dropd.value;    
};

// use an eventlistener for the click event
var subButton = document.getElementById('subButton');
subButton.addEventListener('click', getUserName, false);
var subButtonTwo = document.getElementById('subButtonTwo');
subButtonTwo.addEventListener('click', getOption, false);


$(function () {
   $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
       _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
           var li = $("<li>"),
                   wrapper = $("<div>", {text: item.label});

           if (item.disabled) {
               li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
           }

           $("<span>", {
               style: item.element.attr("option-style"),
               "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
           })
                   .appendTo(wrapper);

           return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
       }
   });


   $("#mySelect")
           .iconselectmenu()
           .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
           .addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");
   });

/*  
function getcurrentChoice() {

var characterSelection = ['MaleWarrior'], ['MaleMage'],    ['FemaleWarrior'], ['FemaleMage'];
var currentChoice = document.getElementById('currentChoice').value;
var resultChoice = document.getElementById('resultChoice');


var subButtons = document.getElementById('subButtons');
subButtons.addEventListener('click', getcurrentChoice, false);


}
```

*/

Sorry for the messy coding, it's not helped that I've tried so many workarounds for each problem I've encountered that I've lost track of what is and isn't working.
I'm pretty sure this is out of control by now, and a waste of your time, but I'm so confused. I'm sure i'm over complicating the matter. 
Thanks in advance again,
Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

https://jsfiddle.net/digitalrevenge/q9z1x6vv/

I've added an `img src` and made some changes to your JS.

I'm not sure if it does exactly what you want but there's no harm in giving it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do this in Javascript, but I have achieved it with jQuery, maybe you can adapt it to Javascript if you like.

Basically...

- Give each option a value
- On selection, or change, empty div#change_this, and check for the value
- If value = # then add html code to div#change_this

You can change the image/add in the stats, I just used some filler.
You will also need to add css and all that, if you have any specific questions about that, please let me know.
Functionality is there though.

Best,
Levi

```css
body {
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    li {
      list-style:none;
    }

    li.fields {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 1em 0;
    }

    li.title {
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size : 1.5em;
      line-height: 2em;
      background: #e3e3e3;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
      border-top: 1px solid white;
    }

    .gamestitle {
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .hide {
      display: none;
    }

    .result {
      height: 200px;
      width: 50%;
      background-color: powderblue;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <div id='gamestitle'>
      <img src = "GAMETITLE.jpg" alt = "Steve's Perilous Capers"/>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <form id='nameForm'>
    <div class='form-uname'>
        <lable id='nameLabel' for='nameField'>Create a username:</lable>
        <input id='nameField' type='text' maxlength='25'></input>
    </div>
    <div class='form-sub'>
        <button id='subButton' type='button'>Enter your name!</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div>
      <p id='result'></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <form>
    Select your Hero please:
    <select name="hero_type" id="mySelect">
    <option value="0">Male Warrior</option>
    <option value="1">Male Mage</option>
    <option value="2">Female Warrior</option>
    <option value="3">Female Mage</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Confirm">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="change_this">
    <p>Yayyy, Male Warrior.</p> <img alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select[name="hero_type"]').click(function() {
        $('#change_this').empty();
        if ($('select[name="hero_type"]').val() == "0"){
            $('#change_this').append('<p>Yayyy, Male Warrior.</p> <img alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">')
         }
         if ($('select[name="hero_type"]').val() == "1"){
             $('#change_this').append('<p>Yayyy, Male Mage.</p> <img alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">')
          }
          if ($('select[name="hero_type"]').val() == "2"){
              $('#change_this').append('<p>Yayyy, Female Warrior</p> <img alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">')
           }
           if ($('select[name="hero_type"]').val() == "3"){
               $('#change_this').append('<p>Yayyy, Female Mage</p> <img alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">')
            }
      })
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks to you all. I see where I'm going wrong now, and yours totally worked without needing JQuery @Digital Revenge. You've all helped me in different ways. I'm so grateful to you all. I can't thank you enough for your time and patience. This is my first question, so I feel unsure as to what to do to repay you all. Is it fairer that Digital Revenge gets the highest commendation as he answered without jQuery? Or for Zachooz for noticing I'd added jQuery code,but not linked the source to import it? I'm so impressed with the level of help received, it's over-whelmed me a bit. Thank you all :D

Comment: You are most welcome. Glad we could help get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks Levi, I had lost all confidence as I care for my Wife 24/7 and my time is so hard to juggle, and my coding becomes hard to keep track of. I've now got the gumption to give libs like jQuery a go, you've all given me a second wind.Thanks again all of you. If ever I can repay you, just message me :)

Answer (score 0):

The src attribute of an image tag points to the location of the image file to use.

You should be somewhat aware of this as your code contains:

```
<img src = "GAMETITLE.jpg" alt = "Steve's Perilous Capers"/>
```

To change the image, simply change the src attribute to point to the location of the new image.

The source of an image tag can be accessed and changed via:

```
document.getElementById("imageId").src="fileToUse";
```

This means you need to add an id to your image tag as so:

```
<img src = "GAMETITLE.jpg" alt = "Steve's Perilous Capers" id="imageId"/>
```

In your case, you want to get the image src from a select field. This means you need to tie the image file locations to your select form as values.

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="location-of-this-image.png">Male Warrior</option>
  <option value="location-of-this-image.png">Male Mage</option>
  <option value="location-of-this-image.png">Female Warrior</option>
  <option value="location-of-this-image.png">Female Mage</option>
</select>
```

To use these values and assign them to the image `src`:

```
document.getElementById("imageId").src=document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
```

If you correctly id your image and select form, give the select form proper values, and put the above line of code in the function you call when choosing and image, your image should change.

**Important Note**

JQuery is a JavaScript library and isn't part of the base language. To use JQuery, you must import it in your html code. You seem to be using JQuery functions, but I don't see where you imported JQuery. This may be causing you problems/breaking your code.

If you do have JQuery imported, the above code can be rewritten using JQuery rather than vanilla JavaScript and it'll look a lot cleaner.